# Rotativa Is not displaying all content

Tags: html, pdf, rotativa

in the site I'm working in they are using Rotativa to export html to pdf, the pages have tables, the problem is that when it exports them some are missing columns or rows that in the html are visible, idk why it is doing that, I really don't fully understand how Rotativa works, when I got here they all ready have it, Can u give me a hint of what may be happening? i've tryed to adjust margins or styles for the html but nothing seems to work because the columns doesnt exist in the pdf output file.

i leave some screenshots of an example of html vs the generated pdf

[image: HTML View]
[image: PDF View Missing two columns]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think the two columns are missing because simply there are too many columns to fit on one page width. Try to reduce cell widths or remove unnecessary columns and see if it works

Comment: how to make all columns fit in one page without removing some columns? is it possible? @Rami Bukhari